# Shopware 6.5: customizing administration module or component

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to restrict parts of the administration dashboard to selected user groups.

Therefore I created a **main.js** under "src/Ressources/app/administration/src" with this content:

```
import './module/sw-dashboard-index';
import './module/sw-dashboard-statistics';
```

and added under "src/Ressources/app/administration/src/module/sw-dashboard-index" a **index.js** with this content:

```
import './acl';
import template from './sw-dashboard-index.html.twig';
import './sw-dashboard-index.scss';
import deDE from './snippet/de-DE.json';
import enGB from './snippet/en-GB.json';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.override('sw-dashboard-index', {
    template,
    snippets: {
        'de-DE': deDE,
        'en-GB': enGB
    },
    inject: {
        acl: 'acl'
    },
});
```

and this template file content:

```
{% block sw_dashboard_index_content_intro_card %}
    <template v-if="acl.can('admin') || !acl.can('dashboard.intro')">
        {% parent() %}
    </template>
{% endblock %}
```

This works for the dashboard. But when I do the same at the statistics under "src/Ressources/app/administration/src/module/sw-dashboard-statistics" and overwrite `Component.override('sw-dashboard-statistics', { ... }`, it doesn't work. The content is not shown, also at the administrator.

The template file content is:

```
{% block sw_dashboard_statistics_intro_stats_today %}
    <template v-if="acl.can('admin') || !acl.can('statistics.stats_today')">
        {% parent() %}
    </template>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea why?

Are the Shopware Docs ( https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/customizing-components#applying-the-override ) already compatible with Shopware 6.5?

Comment: Are there any other plugins installed that may override the component aswell?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, it is an empty shop without any other plugin.

Comment: The block you are overwriting in the statistics, is inside a conditional `<template v-if="hasOrderToday">`. Could that cause the change not being shown?

Comment: No, that could not be the reason, because the content is shown, when i deactivate the extension.